# Как прочитать файлы из папки test?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit, awt

У меня есть метод который ищет расположение одной картинки внутри другой. Для его тестирования в папке тест у меня есть директория с тестовыми изображениями. Проблема в том, что пока мне приходится использовать абсолютные пути для получения доступа к картинкам. Понятно что при попытке открыть проект на другой машине тесты упадут так как структура папок изменится.

Как мне получить доступ к файлам избежав абсолютных путей?

```
@Test
public void whenSubImageNotExistInScreenshotThenReturnPointMinus1() throws IOException {
    final File screenshot = new File("/Users/pavel/GitHub/project/src/test/java/org/project/util/image/screenshot.png");
    final File subImage = new File("/Users/pavel/GitHub/project/src/test/java/org/project/util/image/image.png");
    final Point result = ImageMatcher.findImgFragment(subImage, screenshot);
    System.out.println(result);
    assertTrue(result.getX() != -1);
    assertTrue(result.getY() != -1);
}
```

Надеюсь так же на конструктивную критику самого теста `assertTrue(result.getX() != -1)` и идеи держать тестовые изображения в папке `test`. Остановился на этом так как ничего лучше пока в голову не пришло.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете получить путь к директории, из которой запускается приложение, вызвав:

```
Properties prps = System.getProperties();
String path = prps.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Или конкретный файл при помощи:

```
final File subImage = new File("folder1/folder2/subimage.png");
```

Если начинать писать не с символа `/`, то будет искаться заданный файл по относительному пути, а не абсолютному.

> Надеюсь так же на конструктивную критику самого теста

Ну, если получение **любого**  результата, кроме *-1* для вашего метода считается успешным прохождением оного, то тест написан правильно. Но я бы проверял конкретный ожидаемый результат (или попадание в него с определённой погрешностью).

> держать тестовые изображения в папке `test`

Я бы явно обозначил в папке `test` папку со всеми ресурсами `resources`. Моя IDE, например, позволяет помечать отдельные директории, как test recources. [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) также приводят такую структуру как стандартную.